# Getting started with F# windows application, I cannot find working samples or tutorials

Tags: f#

I have been out of the programming game for a while and thought it would be fun to put together a simple utility application used for gathering data from multiple databases on a sql server.

This is a pretty bare bones app I am envisioning, it would have a connection to a sql server, a place to set a query that would fill a list with named parameters, (database names, widgets, etc), and a section to enter my text with a token that would be replaced.

Below that I would like to have a grid that updated itself while the queries were running even if they were not all finished yet.  This seemed like a neat way to get into F# for me since I was about to build an app to do this in C# so I dug in but after spending six hours on this today I am nowhere.  Is there a good site with very basic tutorials someone can recommend, and with samples that build and run out of the box?

Here is what I did today that did not work:
Downloaded VS2012 Ultimate RC from MSDN.
Went to the online gallery and installed six different sample projects.
Opened each and every one of the sample projects and hit run, not one of them actually ran.

There is so little info out there that I can't tell if this is the expected behavior due to the samples being out of date or if my environment is somehow incorrect (even though I just installed it all from scratch today).

If I could just find the worlds simplest app that would connect to adventure works and load a list of records in a grid I would be far ahead of where I am now, which is stuck spinning my wheels.  If this is the wrong place for this type of question I would welcome advice on where I should ask, and if this is just a dumb idea and this should never be attempted with something like F# and fsharpx I would welcome that feedback as well and would then try to figure out how to do this in C#.

Answer (score 9):

Your bare bones GUI app in F# is just:

```
open System.Windows

[<System.STAThread>]
do
  Application().Run(Window()) |> ignore
```

You need to reference `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework`, `System.Xaml` and `WindowsBase`.

Then it is just a case of adding GUI controls to the window and hooking them up via events. To get a slick user experience I recommend using asynchronous workflows and the `MailboxProcessor` because they make concurrency between the UI thread and background workers so easy. I wrote an article about writing a GUI app using WPF and SQL Server [here](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/using-sql-server-compact-edition.html) (note: paywall).

Comment: A small squabble seems to have erupted here; Jon, you might want to review [this meta Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140393/is-so-for-penniless-freeloaders-advertising-a-paid-service). As a courtesy (for setting expectation, and not causing problems), it would be a good idea to mark paywall links; the usual expectation of an article link is that it will contain actual content.

Comment: @ShaneDelmore - The reason that this question is closed is mainly because there isn't a real question.  A better example would have been.  `I Downloaded this code ... and when I try to compile it I get this error message ...  I have tried ... and ... but I am now stuck.`